# How to write and run more than one code in Python IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

How do you get that code, see below, run in IDLE? I am stuck in my course right now and I could not find an explanation.
I know how to  run in IDLE just one "def" or code, pressing F5, write e.g.
hash_string('udacity', 3) in the shell, "Enter", result. In that code, with more than one code it will not work, of course. For a deeper understanding I want to run it in the Python Online Tutor, condition is that it will work in IDLE or vice versa. 
Further I would like to know, why the input #print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")
results in: #>>> [['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]] Why does 'Bill', 17, appear in the list?

```
# Define a procedure, hashtable_get_bucket,
# that takes two inputs - a hashtable, and
# a keyword, and returns the bucket where the
# keyword could occur.

def hashtable_get_bucket(htable,keyword):
     return htable[hash_string(keyword,len(htable))]


def hash_string(keyword,buckets):
     out = 0
     for s in keyword:
        out = (out + ord(s)) % buckets
     return out

def make_hashtable(nbuckets):
     table = []
     for unused in range(0,nbuckets):
        table.append([])
     return table


#table = [[['Francis', 13], ['Ellis', 11]], [], [['Bill', 17],
#['Zoe', 14]], [['Coach', 4]], [['Louis', 29], ['Rochelle', 4], ['Nick', 2]]]

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")
#>>> [['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]]

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Brick")
#>>> []

#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Lilith")
#>>> [['Louis', 29], ['Rochelle', 4], ['Nick', 2]]
```

Thanks for taking the time reading that post and for your suggestions, too!

Comment: Please describe what you expect and what the functions are supposed to do.

Comment: is this from MIT 6.00x?

Comment: @ Tichodroma: Please refer to the last part (#...) of the code. E.g.
#print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")
#>>> [['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]]

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:CS101,it is "Intro to Computerscience".. Udacity, Lesson 5, Finding Buckets, etc..

Comment: This question is about how to write a Python program with multiple functions.  It has nothing to do with Idle and would be the same if one wrote the program with any other editor.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question first: `table` is a triple list, so a list of lists containing lists. One of those lists is `[['Bill', 17], ['Zoe', 14]]`. Since `hash_string` returns an index, it retrieves one list out of `table`, which happens to be the one with Bill and Zoe.

Further, to run more than one function from within IDLE, you will have to create a new function (a new `def my_assignment` or something) that calls the other functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you write that new function, so that mentioned other functions would be called?

Comment: You might want to run through the Python tutorial again, especially the part on defining functions, https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions